# UWP Update multiple ProgressBars inside ListView

Tags: c#, .net, data-binding, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

In my UWP application, i have a ListView with a definied ItemTemplate. Inside this template, there is a ProgressBar. Now if i start multiple BackgroundTransfers (Downloads) i get all active downloads and add them to a `ObservableCollection<MyClass>` and set this collection as ItemsSource in my ListView. Now my question is, how can i update these ProgressBars? I have read something about the INotifyPropertyChanged, but is this the right and only way to go?

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now my question is, how can i update these ProgressBars? I have read something about the INotifyPropertyChanged, but is this the right and only way to go?

The [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx) interface is used to notify clients, typically binding clients, that a property value has changed. And I am using it to update ProgressBars for BackgroundTransfers.

Following are the main steps:

First, implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface for MyClass:

```
public class MyClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public DownloadOperation DownloadOperation { get; set; }

    private int _progress;
    public int Progress
    {
        get
        {
            return _progress;
        }
        set
        {
            _progress = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
}
```

Second, bind the value of ProgressBar to the Progress property in XAML:

```
<ProgressBar Value="{Binding Progress}" Margin="0,5"></ProgressBar>
```

Then, using [Progress](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh193692(v=vs.110).aspx) to invoke a callback for updating the Progress in code behind:

```
Progress<DownloadOperation> progressCallback = new Progress<DownloadOperation>(DownloadProgress);
await download.AttachAsync().AsTask(cancelToken.Token, progressCallback);


private void DownloadProgress(DownloadOperation download)
    {
        try
        {
            MyClass myClass = myClasses.First(p => p.DownloadOperation == download);
            myClass.Progress = (int)((download.Progress.BytesReceived * 100) / download.Progress.TotalBytesToReceive);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Here is the entire [BackgroundTransferDemo](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=E754412D31A2DF3D!115&authkey=!ACJkE6Ub_aL0_vo&ithint=file%2Czip) for your reference.

Comment: My pleasure! andy :)